# How can I check if a IUser has nickname?

Tags: c#, discord

```
if (user.IsBot == false && (user.Nickname.ToString().Equals(buffer) || user.Username.ToString().Equals(buffer)))
{
    await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + message[new Random().Next(5)] + user.Mention);
}
```

If user doesn't have a nickname it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if Nickname is null first. In this case I would propose something like:

```
if (user.Nickname != null && user.IsBot == false)
{
    if (user.Nickname.ToString().Equals(buffer) || user.Username.ToString().Equals(buffer)))
    {
        await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + message[new Random().Next(5)] + user.Mention);
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
if (user != null)
{
    if (user.Nickname != null && user.IsBot == false)
    {
        if (user.Nickname.ToString().Equals(buffer) || user.Username.ToString().Equals(buffer)))
        {
            await ReplyAsync(Context.User.Mention + message[new Random().Next(5)] + user.Mention);
        }
    }
}
```

if user can be null too.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I use discord.foxbot reference.Can you recommend me another?

Comment: I can't help you since I've never did anything related to Discord when it comes to programming.